# Passing an array value into the jQuery selector method?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

At the moment in my JS I statically define which input ID's I want to associate my datepicker script with.

Like so:

```
$('datepicker1').glDatePicker();
```

However to make this dynamic I have refactored this into a for loop so that for multiple fields that need a datepicker I can call them in that loop.

```
dateArray[y] =  "datePicker" + i;
//out of loop scope

for (i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++)
    {
        $(dateArray[i]).glDatePicker();

    }
```

It does not seem to work , I have checked that there are values in the array by printing the values to the log.

Is this a limitation of jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: Is `datepicker1` the tag name ?

Comment: You can avoid loops, and make a simple single call (see my answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set it as an id with `"#"`

```
 $("#" + dateArray[i]).glDatePicker();
```

Comment: THanks, cant believe I missed that

Answer (score 1):

> which input ID's I want to associate my datepicker script with.

i think you missed the id selector

```
$('#'+ dateArray[i]).glDatePicker();
---^---here
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to make a single jQuery call to `glDatePicker()`, by concatenating all ids into a string

```
var allIds = '';
for (i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) {
  allIds += '#' + dateArray[i] + ',';
}
$(allIds).glDatePicker();
```

---

Or even better, put a class to all those fields, and simply call

```
$(".datepicker").glDatePicker();
```

---

There is still another single call solution (assuming all your ids start with "datePicker"):

```
$('[id^="datePicker"]').glDatePicker(); // selects all elements that have id starting with datePicker
```